# Maximum value of unsigned char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unsigned-char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char i=0x80;
    printf("%d",i<<1);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this program print 256?

As I understand this, since 0x80= 0b10000000, and unsigned char has 8 bits, the '1' should overflow after left shift and the output should be 0, not 256.

Comment: Don't want to post as an answer because I'm not 100% sure, but isn't it because %d is an integer? So, the code behind the scenes probably assigns `i<<1` to an integer to print it, which means that it fits and doesn't overflow. Try doing `printf("%c", i<<1);`?

Comment: @Stephen: Should have posted the answer ;)

Comment: @Stephen:The output is blank when I use %c.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I was sort of on the right track. Sorry %c didn't work - I didn't have a compiler to hand to check it!

Comment: On most compilers, `i << n` will produce an integer, regardless of the original type.

Comment: @BrianS On all compilers, it will produce an integer unless `n` is negative or equal to or greater than the number of bits in the integer, in which the behavior is undefined and for non-integer types the bitwise-shift operator MUST create a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a result of C's integer promotion rules. Essentially, most any variable going into an expression is "promoted" so that operations like this do not lose precision. Then, it's passed as an `int` into `printf`, according to C's variable arguments rules.

If you'd want what you're looking for, you'd have to cast back to `unsigned char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char i=0x80;
    printf("%d",((unsigned char)(i<<1)));
    return 0;
}
```

Note: using `%c` as specified in Stephen's comment won't work because `%c` expects an integer too.

EDIT: Alternately, you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char i=0x80;
    unsigned char res = i<<1;
    printf("%d",res);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char i=0x80;
    printf("%d",(i<<1) & 0xFF);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you cast `(i<<1)` to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Nathon: Isn't that what I did?

Comment: Weird, I must have my blinders turned on.

Comment: "using %c as specified in Stephen's comment won't work because %c expects an integer too." --> `"%c"` and `"%d"` both accept an `int`.  `"%c"` converts its `int` to an `unsigned char` and then prints that character.

Comment: @R..: For _completeness_, it should be mentioned that `unsigned char` promotes to `signed int` **or** `unsigned int` depending on whether or not all the values of `unsigned char` can be represented in a `signed int`, and that the `"%c"` specifier expects a `signed int` which is one of several integer types.

Comment: @NisseEngström on what platform are there values of unsigned char that can't be represented as a signed int?

Comment: @BillyONeal: I don't know of any myself, but I believe it is allowed by the (-99) C standard. There are some interesting platforms mentioned in [this Usenet thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/comp.lang.c/kSQi_DRiXpw/aL1GITig9I4J).

Comment: @Nisse: I try to avoid hypothetical details about platforms that in all likelihood do not actually exist when answering beginner questions.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Some of the systems mentioned are in the DSP 56xxx family. With a little bit of googling, one can find the [DSP56000 Family C Compiler Manual](http://www.google.se/url?q=http://www-mipp.fnal.gov/TPC/DAQ/56KCCUM.pdf&sa=U&ved=0CBMQFjAAahUKEwjiv_iupNnIAhXi33IKHYqCB3c&usg=AFQjCNE14jYzIE6S80MB_jTxJvr7n8x8QA). Section 4.4 says that "**sizeof(char) is equal to sizeof(int)**", and section 4.4.1 lists the maximum values of the integer types: "**unsigned char** ... **0xFFFFFF**" and "**int** ... **8388607**".

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the format specifically for printing unsigned.

```
printf("%u",(unsigned char)(i<<1));
```

Comment: Due to C's promotion rules, the argument will most likely be passed to `printf` as `signed int`, not `unsigned`. You should cast the argument to a type that matches the format specifier.